# How to safely use packages in .lco files?

Tags: koma-script

I want to create an .lco file to customize some things for my `scrlttr2` document.

I need to change the page dimensions like bottommargin and include graphics. I do know that you should not use `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` in .lco files since they could be used after `\begin{document}`.

Therefore I tried to check in the .lco file if the package had been included before and if not provide a helpful warning. However, after trying this, this does also not work after `\begin{document}`...

How do I check for previous loading of packages to give the user a helpful error message in .lco files?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{filecontents*}{mylco.lco}
    \ProvidesFile{mylco}[2023-04-21 my lco file]
    
    \@ifpackageloaded{geometry}{
        \newgeometry{bottom=28mm}}{}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \LoadLetterOption{mylco}
\end{document}
```

Comment: where did you get this `\LCOError` command from?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: https://github.com/komascript/notepaper-wsu

Comment: well look into the lco files in the github and check their code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The `\LCOError` had nothing to do with the error. I have removed it now from the question as I understand it might be misleading. The problem is the `\@ifpackageloaded` is there a version that can be used after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: \@ifpackageloaded works fine here. But you can't use \geometry in the document body.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: `\@ifpackageloaded` does lead to `can only used in preamble \@ifpackageloaded`. So it is the cause of the problem. You are right, though, that `\geometry` also does not work after preamble. I have replaced it with `\newgeometry` which does not throw an extra error but still does not work...

Comment: As I wrote: it works for me. Since 2021 \@ifpackageloaded can be used in the document too see https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews34.pdf page 4. Consider to update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you for the hint. I did need to update and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a issue of missing updates as explained in a comment and has been solved after update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work with older LaTeX distributions.

Updating to a version from 2022 or later will allow calling `\@ifpackageloaded` also after `\begin{document}` and therefore allow easy checking.